Pyspark optimal method for subtracting grouped rows in dataframe
In a dataframe like the table below, I need to subtract the sum of two rows from another row, all grouped by type of CORP and BRANCH (where the first row already includes the other two).



CORP
BRANCH
MARKET
AMOUNT




C0
B1
EUROPE
569


C0
B1
AMERICA
4595


C0
B1
SO-AMERICA
221


C0
B1
NO-AMERICA
545


C0
B1
ASIA
989


C0
B2
EUROPE
65


C0
B2
AMERICA
6547


C0
B2
SO-AMERICA
669


C0
B2
NO-AMERICA
2258


C0
B2
ASIA
54


C1
B3
EUROPE
12222


C1
B3
AMERICA
8453


C1
B3
SO-AMERICA
22


C1
B3
NO-AMERICA
545


C1
B3
ASIA
99



For example, the row "C0 B1 AMERICA" will be equal to 4595 - (221 + 545) = 3829.
I've come up with these two solutions. The explain function seems to show they have the same cost, but which one could be better?
df_res1 = df_res1.withColumn('america', F.when(F.col('MARKET') == 'AMERICA', F.col('AMOUNT')).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
                 .withColumn('no_so_america', F.when(F.col('MARKET').isin(['NO_AMERICA', 'SO_AMERICA']), F.col('AMOUNT'))\
                                               .otherwise(F.lit(0)))

win_perc = W.partitionBy('CORP', 'BRANCH')

df_res1 = df_res1.withColumn('tmp', F.col('america')-F.sum('no_so_america').over(win_perc))\
                 .withColumn('AMOUNT',\
                            F.when(F.col('tmp') > F.lit(0), F.col('tmp'))
                             .otherwise(F.col('AMOUNT')))\
                 .drop('america', 'no_so_america', 'tmp') 

df_res1.explain(mode='cost')

No.2
df_sum_no_so = df_res2.where(F.col('MARKET').isin(['NO_AMERICA', 'SO_AMERICA']))\
                      .groupBy('CORP', 'BRANCH')\
                      .agg(F.sum('AMOUNT').alias('sum_no_so_america'))

df_res2 = df_res2.join(df_sum_no_so, ['CORP', 'BRANCH'], 'left')

df_res2 = df_res2.withColumn('AMOUNT',\
                            F.when(F.col('MARKET') == 'AMERICA', F.col('AMOUNT') - F.col('sum_no_so_america'))\
                            .otherwise(F.col('AMOUNT')))

df_res2.explain(mode='cost')


You can use @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
to perform operation on one group and output one or multiple rows based on the calculations on the whole group data.
I have provided a dummy row addition as an example just to show how to do it.
In your case you can join this new table with your own source table.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.pandas.functions import PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("C0", "B1", "EUROPE", 569),
    ("C0", "B1", "AMERICA", 4595),
    ("C0", "B1", "SO-AMERICA", 221),
    ("C0", "B1", "NO-AMERICA", 545),
    ("C0", "B1", "ASIA", 989),
    ("C0", "B2", "EUROPE", 65),
    ("C0", "B2", "AMERICA", 6547),
    ("C0", "B2", "SO-AMERICA", 669),
    ("C0", "B2", "NO-AMERICA", 2258),
    ("C0", "B2", "ASIA", 54),
    ("C1", "B3", "EUROPE", 12222),
    ("C1", "B3", "AMERICA", 8453),
    ("C1", "B3", "SO-AMERICA", 22),
    ("C1", "B3", "NO-AMERICA", 545),
    ("C1", "B3", "ASIA", 99)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["CORP", "BRANCH", "MARKET", "AMOUNT"])

schema = StructType([
    StructField("CORP", StringType()),
    StructField("BRANCH", StringType()),
    StructField("MARKET", StringType()),
    StructField("AMOUNT", IntegerType())
])


@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def adjust_america(pdf):
    america = pdf[pdf['MARKET'] == 'AMERICA']['AMOUNT'].sum()
    so_america = pdf[pdf['MARKET'] == 'SO-AMERICA']['AMOUNT'].sum()
    no_america = pdf[pdf['MARKET'] == 'NO-AMERICA']['AMOUNT'].sum()
    america_adjusted = america - (so_america + no_america)
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'CORP': [pdf['CORP'].iloc[0], "dummy_C"],
        'BRANCH': [pdf['BRANCH'].iloc[0], "dummy_B"],
        'MARKET': ["AMERICA_ADJUSTED", "dummy_market"],
        'AMOUNT': [america_adjusted, -9232]

    })


result_df = df.groupBy("CORP", "BRANCH").apply(adjust_america)
result_df.show()

Output :
+-------+-------+----------------+------+
|   CORP| BRANCH|          MARKET|AMOUNT|
+-------+-------+----------------+------+
|     C0|     B1|AMERICA_ADJUSTED|  3829|
|dummy_C|dummy_B|    dummy_market| -9232|
|     C0|     B2|AMERICA_ADJUSTED|  3620|
|dummy_C|dummy_B|    dummy_market| -9232|
|     C1|     B3|AMERICA_ADJUSTED|  7886|
|dummy_C|dummy_B|    dummy_market| -9232|
+-------+-------+----------------+------+

